# Save listview data to my access database

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been searching this question for a lot of times but i couldn't get the right answer. Can somebody help me how to transfer all my data from a listview to my access database. Is it possible ? Thanks for help.

Please, can anyone help me with this.

Comment: how is structure of your list view?

Comment: What kind of data is in this listview?

Comment: Let say I have five columns in my listview some are numbers and the other are just text.

Answer (score 0):

With 3 steps:

1. desing your database according your list view column
2. loop through list view rows([ListView.ListViewItemCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx))
3. add each row to database

Comment: I'm pretty much happy with your answer. I'm actually doing the looping part now. But I'm kinda lost with that looping part. how do i do it . thanks so much.

Comment: @Red Gabanan: see my link in answer